# Custom method in AngularJs with post data

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angular-resource

My problem is this. I have in my application a Service using $resource and a controller in web api.

this is my service in angular

```
GarantiaService = function ($resource) 
{
     return $resource("../../api/garantia/:id", null,
     {
        'update': { method: 'PUT' },
        'renovar': { method: 'RENOVAR'}
     });
};
```

this is my controller

```
RenovarController = function ($scope, $routeParams, GarantiaService) {
    $scope.Garantia = { Id: 0 };

    $scope.ActualizarGarantia = function () {

        GarantiaService.renovar({ id: $scope.Garantia.Id }, $scope.Garantia, function () {
            //$location.path('#/');
        }, function () {
            alert("Error en la persistencia");
        });
    };
};
```

and in web api i created a custom method

```
    [AcceptVerbs("RENOVAR")]
    public IHttpActionResult Renovar(int id, Garantia garantia)
    {


        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

the thing is i keep getting garantia null in c# and i'm not passing a null object in angular. 
Is it a problem in my service or in c#?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: What does your implementation of `Garantia` on the server side look like?

Comment: Seconded.  Do `$scope.Garantia` and `Garantia` have the same definition?

Comment: it is the exact same object. With the methods put and post there is no problem.

Comment: I think you shouldn't use a custom method RENOVAR, try POST instead.

Comment: if i use post how will i route it? sorry but im new to web api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this

jscontroller

```
RenovarController = function ($scope, $routeParams, GarantiaService) {
    $scope.Garantia = { Id: 0 };

    $scope.ActualizarGarantia = function () {

        GarantiaService.renovar({ garantia: $scope.Garantia }, function () {
            //$location.path('#/');
        }, function () {
            alert("Error en la persistencia");
        });
    };
};
```

web api:

```
[AcceptVerbs("RENOVAR")]
public IHttpActionResult Renovar(string garantia)
{
     Garantia deser = (Garantia)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(garantia,typeof(Garantia));

     return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call the method like this:

```
GarantiaService.renovar({ id: $scope.Garantia.Id, garantia: $scope.Garantia, }, function () {
            //$location.path('#/');
        }, function () {
            alert("Error en la persistencia");
        });
```